# Mostrar la fecha en dd-MM-aaaa

Tags: java, mysql, date

Buenas, estoy haciendo un programa en Java conectándome a una base de datos **MySql**
al ejecutar el programa, tienes la posibilidad de ver los datos que están guardados en la base de datos o tambien añadir datos nuevos. El problema esta en que me visualiza la fecha en formato **aaaa-MM-dd** y para guardar datos tambien lo tengo que introducir así. Que podría hacer para que me visualice la fecha en formato **dd-MM-aaaa**. Habria alguna posibilidad tanto de visualizar como de introducir la fecha sin cambiar el formato en la base de datos. Ejemplo que en la BD se guarde como **aaaa-MM-dd** pero al visualizar los datos o introducirlo sea **dd-MM-aaaa**

**Foto de la base de datos:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Código para consultar la BD:**

```
public boolean consultarTodo() throws SQLException
    {
        try
        {
            objetoBBDD.resultado = objetoBBDD.sentencia.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM clientes");
            objetoBBDD.resultado.first();    
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        return false;
    }
```

**Metodo para visualizar los datos en los TextField:**

```
public void visualizarDatos()
    {
        
        try {
            jtfcodigoCliente.setText(objetoBBDD.resultado.getString("codCliente"));
            jtfnombre.setText(objetoBBDD.resultado.getString("nombre"));
            jtfapellidos.setText(objetoBBDD.resultado.getString("apellidos"));
            jtffechaNacimiento.setText(objetoBBDD.resultado.getString("fechaNac"));
            jtfdireccion.setText(objetoBBDD.resultado.getString("direccion"));
            jtfpoblacion.setText(objetoBBDD.resultado.getString("poblacion"));
            jtfcodigoPostal.setText(objetoBBDD.resultado.getString("codPostal"));
            jtfprovincia.setText(objetoBBDD.resultado.getString("provincia"));
            jtftelefono.setText(objetoBBDD.resultado.getString("telefono"));
        } catch (SQLException e){e.printStackTrace();}        
    }
```

**Método para añadir clientes nuevos:**

```
public void asignarDatos()
    {
        objClientes.setCodigoCliente(Integer.parseInt(jtfcodigoCliente.getText()));
        objClientes.setNombre(jtfnombre.getText());
        objClientes.setApellidos(jtfapellidos.getText());
        objClientes.setDireccion(jtfdireccion.getText());
        objClientes.setPoblacion(jtfpoblacion.getText());
        objClientes.setCodigoPostal(jtfcodigoPostal.getText());
        objClientes.setProvincia(jtfprovincia.getText());
        objClientes.setTelefono(jtftelefono.getText());
        objClientes.setFechaNacimiento(jtffechaNacimiento.getText());
    }
```

**Clase clientes:**

```
public class Clientes 
{
    private int codigoCliente;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private String direccion;
    private String poblacion;
    private String codigoPostal;
    private String provincia;
    private String telefono;
    private String fechaNacimiento;
    
    public Clientes()
    {
        super();
        codigoCliente = 0;
        nombre = new String();
        apellidos = new String();
        direccion = new String();
        poblacion = new String();
        codigoPostal = new String();
        provincia = new String();
        telefono = new String();
        fechaNacimiento = new String();
    }
    
    public Clientes(int codigoCliente,String nombre,String apellidos,String direccion,String poblacion,String codigoPostal,String provincia,
            String telefono,String fechaNacimiento)
    {
        super();
        this.codigoCliente = codigoCliente;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.poblacion = poblacion;
        this.codigoPostal = codigoPostal;
        this.provincia = provincia;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public int getCodigoCliente() {
        return codigoCliente;
    }

    public void setCodigoCliente(int codigoCliente) {
        this.codigoCliente = codigoCliente;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public String getPoblacion() {
        return poblacion;
    }

    public void setPoblacion(String poblacion) {
        this.poblacion = poblacion;
    }

    public String getCodigoPostal() {
        return codigoPostal;
    }

    public void setCodigoPostal(String codigoPostal) {
        this.codigoPostal = codigoPostal;
    }

    public String getProvincia() {
        return provincia;
    }

    public void setProvincia(String provincia) {
        this.provincia = provincia;
    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getFechaNacimiento() {
        return fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public void setFechaNacimiento(String fechaNacimiento) {
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    }
}
```

**Imagen del programa:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Está muy bien que quieras mostrar los datos en formato dd-MM-aaaa pero ¿Introducirlos en ese formato? Muy mala idea, al final tendrás un lío de fechas y posibles datos erróneos. Introducelos en el formato en que los guarda la BD (aaaa-mm-dd) aunque tengas que convertir antes de introducir, y solo conviértelos para presentarlos en pantalla.

Comment: Vale de acuerdo, pero como hago eso con SimpleDateFormat() ? Es que no se donde puedo ponerlo en mi codigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crearte una función que te devuelva la fecha formateada en el formato que tu desees. Te recomendaría crearla en una clase de utilidades. Por ejemplo:

```
public static String formatFecha(Date fecha) {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(fecha) 
}
```

Después, sólo tienes que invocar la función en el método visualizarDatos de la siguiente manera.

```
jtffechaNacimiento.setText(Utilidades.formatFecha(objetoBBDD.resultado.getDate("fechaNac")));
```